# how to post xml to solr in mvc.net(c#)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, solr

I am using solr search in my mvc.net application, all the search is working well.

but now i want to post my xml to solr by code(c#), so plz tell me how i post my xml to solr using mvc.net c(#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the SolrNet project: http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/  It provides a client library; that may be overkill for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **System.Net.WebRequest** class. Here's a nice article that contains code samples:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPOSTsAndHTTPGETsWithWebClientAndCAndFakingAPostBack.aspx